# sendmail and certs

Tags: linux, sendmail, ssl

I am trying to set up sendmail for our company on a CentOS 6.6-Release server.
Specifically, I want to use SSL, so that passwords are sent encrypted.

```
ls /etc/mail/ssl
intermediate.crt    ourdomain.crt    ourdomain.csr 
RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem
```

All right, so I set up my sendmail.mc with these lines:

```
define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/mail/ssl')
define(`confCACERT', `/etc/mail/ssl/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem')
define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/mail/ssl/ourdomain.crt')
define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/mail/ssl/ourdomain.key')
```

I'm not entirely sure that the certificates are correct...

And then ..

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Name=MTA')
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')
```

At this point, I can send and receive e-mail from localhost (logged in and
using mutt), and from within our network.  But I can't add my e-mail account
to an iPhone, or an iPad, and that's what the bosses want.

So I want the only connections to be on port 465, so I comment out this
line:

```
dnlDAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Name=MTA')
```

I then rebuild sendmail.cf..

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```

I restart sendmail, and I try to send an e-mail from localhost..

```
[Feb 11 14:59:30 mail sm-msp-queue[5407]: t1BEs2kT005208:
to=root@ourseconddomain.com, ctladdr=me (500/502),
delay=00:05:28, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=420515,
relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused
by [127.0.0.1]
```

Sendmail is definitely running..

```
[root@mail mail]# ps -ef | grep sendmail
root      5581     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: accepting
connections
smmsp     5590     1  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: Queue
runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
root      5598  3296  0 15:12 pts/0    00:00:00 grep sendmail
```

And in /etc/mail/local-host-names, I have:

```
localhost
mydomain.com
mail.ourdomain.com[/code]
```

In /etc/hosts..

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4
localhost4.localdomain4 mail.mydomain.com
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6
localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.1.13 mail.ourdomain.com
```

I can't fathom why sendmail is refusing connections from localhost...